# Convert array and post to sql database

Tags: php, sql

here is my array:

```
Array ( [0] => Natural Chlid 1 [1] => Natural Chlid 2 [2] => Natural Chlid 3 )
```

How would i do the following:

a) convert the data so that it could be recalled via a php query and inserted into db

b) add the data to only ONE FIELD of the database (in this case a field called 'children')

Comment: Do you need to have a query condition based on the data in that field?

Comment: re question b... normalize your table so that you can store the data cleanly in a 1:many relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

```
$data = array(
    0 => 'Natural Chlid 1',
    1 => 'Natural Chlid 2',
    2 => 'Natural Chlid 3'
);

// To save

$link = mysqli_connect('hostname', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$serialized = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, serialize($data));

$result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table ('id', 'children') VALUES (123, '$serialized')");

if (!$result) {
    printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error());
}

// To retrieve

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=123");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(result);

$data = unserialize($row['children']);
```

Comment: just a quick question Saul, the $data = array() can that be session data ? $_SESSION['children']

Comment: thats great, but i have a php error now

mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: @Xavier: Of course. `serialize()` accepts all values, even objects and constants.

Comment: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

according to the php manual `mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode ] )`

what would the $resultmode represent ?

Comment: @Xavier: It's the same issue as with `real_escape`: mysqli wants to know on which connection `$link` the query needs to be executed.

Comment: every-time i run the script i get a mysql_query expects parameter 1 to be mysqli - (array given) (string given)

what would $link have to represent in my code?

Sorry i am a newbie :)

Comment: @Xavier: `$link` would have to represent a connection to a database. The code sample assumes MySQL.

Comment: `$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mutli_page_form');
 $data = array($_SESSION['children']);
 $serialized = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, serialize($data));
 mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into wills_children ('will', 'children') VALUES ('123', '$serialized')");`

it is not sending the data to the database at all... i have no reason why! the data is serialized tho